# What is the role of the capacitor in clamper circuit?

Tags: diodes, voltage-regulator, dc, diode-clamp

[image]

I am having some difficulty in understanding the use of a capacitor in the clamper circuit (attached above.) I read that it maintains a constant potential across it, but then why do we not use a battery instead if we just want a constant potential?  Assume that Vin is a sinusoidal input.

Comment: What is Vin? What source, what kind of signal?

Comment: @TimWilliams Vin is the input voltage, can be considered as sinusoidal

Comment: It the amplitude and frequency known?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, you can assume it, its immaterial i guess.

Comment: Assuming your input is AC, It's used for the DC level shifting. When the diode is reverse-biased, the output voltage is approximately equal to the input voltage, the capacitor will charge up to the peak voltage. During the negative half cycle the diode becomes forward biased and the capacitor is essentially in series to the input - so voltage adds up. It's like 2 batteries connected in series where the negative terminal is connected to the positive terminal of another battery - you essentially add up the voltage. In this case you get 0V to 30V if your input goes from 15 Volts to -15 Volts.

Comment: @15Volts If the diode is reverse biased then shouldn't the output be Vin-Vc(potential across capacitor)? and also when the diode becomes forward biased, then shouldn't the Vout be 0? Assuming the diode to be ideal,

Comment: When the diode is reverse-biased (in other words, cathode voltage is more than the anode voltage), it acts as an open circuit, as if you removed the diode (in an ideal world). Now the charged capacitor is effectively in series with the input signal, resulting in an output voltage of Vin + Vc. When the diode is forward-biased, the output voltage is approximately equal to the input voltage (Vin) and the capacitor is charged up. The cycle continues.

Comment: @15Volts When it is forward biased,if we assume it to be an ideal diode then we can replace it with a wire, in that case the output voltage should be 0?

Comment: Yes, when the diode is forward biased, it's like replacing it with a wire; the output goes to zero (when in stable state, after a cycle). And when the diode is in reversed biased mode, it's like opening the wire and output goes close to 2x of the Vin, actually it depends on the charge of the capacitor so it's Vin (input voltage) + Vc (capacitor voltage) . In layman's term the diode here acts as a switch like that controlling the charging and discharging of the capacitor. But again, nothing is ideal, so in reality there will be a small voltage drop (~0.7V for IN4007) across the diode.

Comment: @green_32 Oops correction - I noticed in the first comment of mine I said "reverse-bias" makes capacitor charge up. In reality the forward bias makes the capacitor charge up, the reverse bias puts the capacitor in series to the line, so you boost voltage. Sorry for the confusion. Can't edit that comment now. The next comments are ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several interesting experiments can be done with this simple circuit of three elements in a loop.

### Rechargeable battery

It is quite possible to use a battery instead of a capacitor especially if it is rechargeable. You can only connect a small resistor in series with the diode to limit the charging current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjcEra.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: STEP 1]

### Regular battery

If it is a regular battery, it will not even need a diode, but you will have to replace the battery after a while.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDtyg1.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 2]

### Floating voltage source

What you cannot use there is a grounded voltage source Vref. But if the input voltage source Vin is floating, you can swap Vref and Vin...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP5MTQ.png)</sup>

... and the result would be the same.

[image: STEP 3]

### Floating capacitor

The "battery examples" above are somewhat "textbook"; their purpose is more illustrative. The capacitor is the most convenient and practical implementation of this "voltage-shifting" idea having the advantages of a *floating rechargeable voltage source*.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f854zf.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 4]

### Grounded capacitor

It is interesting that if we swap the capacitor and  diode, we get the ordinary half-wave rectifier.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftSRT0.png)</sup>

[image: STEP 5]

### Conclusions

Regardless of how the elements are arranged, it is the same circuit of three elements in a loop - AC source, capacitor and diode.

Depending on whether we use the voltage across the diode or across the capacitor as the output, the circuit is either a *clamper* or a *half-wave rectifier*.

If the diode were not there, the capacitor would alternately charge and discharge, but with the diode present it only charges up to the AC amplitude.

Comment: Then is there any specific use-case of the capacitor here? because I have generally seen capacitor to be used in such circuits

Comment: @green_32, The capacitor is the most convenient and practical implementation of this "voltage-shifting" idea. The battery example is more "textbook"; its purpose is illustrative.

Answer (score 3):

The capacitor in a clamper circuit shifts the waveform to a desired DC level without changing the actual appearance of the applied signal. By adjusting the value of the capacitor, you can control the amount of DC shift in the output waveform. The purpose is not to provide a constant voltage like a battery.

Comment: This trick was widely used in old TV receivers. I think the name of the circuit was "DC restoration circuit".

Comment: @Circuitfantasist I am curious to the use of this circuit in TV, can you tell ?

Comment: @green_32, I had seen it in a book about TV receivers in the 80's... but I have to look for it in the basement... I think the idea was to automatically keep the transistor (tube) "off" and only if a pulse of significant amplitude comes, then  to make it "on" (something like "level discriminator"). At that time, it was very prestigious to repair receivers and I had decided to master this art. But soon I realized that I am not for this "craft" work...